# Java Generics create list of objects which extends class A and implements interface B

Tags: java, generics

Consider this scenario

```
public abstract class A{

}

public interface B{

}
```

How would I create a List of objects which extend A and implement B?

```
List<? extends A implements B> list = new List();
```

Thanks

Comment: `class XXX extends A implements B {}`?

Comment: That should work, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use '&' operator and declare the unknown class as a type parameter like below. The advantage of this vs declaring a `class XXX extends B implement A` is that your code will work with any such a class that satisfy the constraints not just `XXX` descendants.

```
import java.util.*;

interface A {};

class B {};

class Test {

    public <T extends B & A> List<T> asList(Collection<T> elements) {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(elements.size());
        for (T element : elements) result.add(element);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer better, but for some reason, it won't allow me to declare a list in the same fashion: private <T extends A & B> List<T> list

Comment: Nor does: private List<? extends A & B> list

Comment: @JavaNoob I guess that your intention is to declare a object field. In that case you would need to make the Test class generic and use the Type parameter as the list type: ```class Test<T extends B & A>``` ... ```private List<T> list```.

Comment: Notice that the order matters here. The A & B won’t work but B & A does. The class must go before any interface. I'm affraid I cannot tell you why it is so; it's a non sense limitation that hopefully will be drop in future language versions... it might be a compiler bug also.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, this is not supported with wildcard generics. This can be done with Type generics.

```
public abstract class A{}
public interface B{}

public class Match extends A implements B{}
public class NotMatch1 implements B{}
public class NotMatch2 extends A{}

public class MyChecketList<T extends A&B> extends ArrayList<T>{}

public void use(){
    List<Match> a = new MyChecketList<>();//valid
    List<NotMatch1> b = new MyChecketList<>();//compiler error
    List<NotMatch2> c = new MyChecketList<>();//compiler error

    MyChecketList<Match> d = new MyChecketList<>();//valid
    MyChecketList<NotMatch1> e = new MyChecketList<>();//compiler error
    MyChecketList<NotMatch2> f = new MyChecketList<>();//compiler error
}
```